# 500 server error only on mobile devices

Tags: android, iphone

I am getting a 500 server error on an HTML5 responsive template I bought,but only on mobile devices. It works fine on my desktop PC. I have contacted hostgator and they initially found a missing png file in a css file, so I contacted the theme developer, who said to move the png file to the specific location. I did that with no luck, he then said to contact my hosting provider (hostgator). They checked the error log again and found nothing. The url is thewalrusisme.com and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Internal Server Error. Website developer or web server admin should be able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Error 500**
This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.

Comment: you write down here...which was already showing in device browser with 500 error..